# How can I pass Data from one fragment to another one?

Tags: android

Hello i am working with fragment to pass data from one fragment to another with My Model object like Student with (id,name),but i cant able to pass and view data in second fragment from pass first fragment.

Comment: There are more than one way.. You can use BroadcastReceiver or library like Otto.

Comment: In order to get most out of StackOverflow, please be precise about your question and provide detailed information about what you've tried so far and how those attempts failed. See the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. use static variable
2. if you use view pager then update fragment when a fragment is change
3. In Fragment transaction send data in constructor when when a fragment is replace

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from one fragment to other using **constructor** or using **setArgument**

**Using Constructor**

```
ModelStudent student = new ModelStudent(1, "ABCD");
FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo(student);
```

**Using setArgument**

```
FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("STUDENT", student);
fragmentTwo.setArguments(bundle);
```

---

**Fragment 1**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private Button btnPassData;

    public FragmentOne() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frgament_one, container, false);

        btnPassData = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPassData);
        btnPassData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ModelStudent student = new ModelStudent(1, "ABCD");
                // first way
                //FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo(student);
                // or second way
                FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("STUDENT", student);
                fragmentTwo.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content, fragmentTwo).commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

---

**Fragment 2**

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private ModelStudent modelStudent;
    private TextView txtStudent;

    public FragmentTwo() {
    }

    public FragmentTwo(ModelStudent modelStudent) {
        this.modelStudent = modelStudent;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frgament_two, container, false);

        txtStudent = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtStudent);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        ModelStudent student = (ModelStudent) bundle.getSerializable("STUDENT");
        txtStudent.setText("RollNo: " + student.getRollNo() + " Name: " + student.getName());

        return rootView;
    }
```